# C++ class functions calling fortran subroutine

Tags: c++, linux, fortran

Okay so I am trying to make my code work. It is a simple C++ program with a class "CArray". This class has 2 properties, the array size, and the value. I want the main C++ program to create two instances of the class CArray. In the class CArray, I have a function called "AddArray( CArray )" where it adds another array to the current array. The problem I am stuck with, is that I want the function "AddArray" to add the two arrays in fortran. I know, much more complicated, but that is what I need. I am having issues with linking the two inside the class code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CArray
{
    public:
    CArray();
    ~CArray();
    int Size;
    int*    Val;

    void    SetSize( int );
    void    SetValues();
    void    GetArray();


    extern "C" 
    {
    void    Add( int*, int*, int*, int*);
    void    Subtract( int*, int*, int*, int*);
    void    Muliply( int*, int*, int *, int* );
    }
    void    AddArray( CArray );
    void    SubtractArray( CArray );
    void    MultiplyArray( CArray );
};
```

Also here is the CArray function file.

```
#include "Array.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

CArray::CArray()
{
}


CArray::~CArray()
{
}


void CArray::SetSize( int s )
{
    Size = s;
    for ( int i=0; i<s; i++ )
    {
    Val = new int[Size];
    }
}


void CArray::SetValues()
{
    for ( int i=0; i<Size; i++ )
    {
    cout << "Element " << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> Val[i];
    }
}


void CArray::GetArray()
{
    for ( int i=0; i<Size; i++ )
    {
    cout << Val[i] << " ";
    }
}


void CArray::AddArray( CArray a )
{
    if ( Size == a.Size )
    {
    Add(&Val, &a.Val);
    }
    else
    {
    cout << "Array dimensions do not agree!" << endl;
    }
}


void CArray::SubtractArray( CArray a )
{
    Subtract( &Val, &a, &Size, &a.Size);
    GetArray();
}
```

Here is my Fortran code.

```
module SubtractArrays
    use ico_c_binding
    implicit none

    contains

    subroutine Subtract(a,b,s1,s2) bind(c,name='Subtract')
    integer s1,s2
    integer a(s1),b(s2)

    if ( s1.eq.s2 )
        do i=1,s1
        a(i) = a(i) - b(i)
        end
    return 
    end
end
```

If someone could just help me with setting me up to send arrays of integers from C++ classes to fortran I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you,

Josh Derrick

Comment: In the Fortran code, shouldn't `INTEGER` be `INTEGER(C_INT)`?

Answer (score 0):

You must realise that `Val` is already a pointer. So to call the subtraction routine, you would simply do this:

```
void CArray::SubtractArray( CArray a )
{
    Subtract( Val, a.val, &Size, &a.Size);
    GetArray();
}
```

Please note that I don't know Fortran, so I can't comment on the Fortran part of code.

---

Additionally, there are tons of problems in your code.

1. `SetSize(int s)` does total nonsense. It allocates `s` arrays of `s` size each, and leaks all but the last one. You probably just meant this:

   ```
   void CArray::SetSize( int s )
   {
       Size = s;
       delete[] Val;
       Val = new int[Size];
   }
   ```
2. You're leaking memory all over the place. You should not manage memory manually, and simply use `std::vector`:

   ```
   class CArray
   {
     public:
       CArray();

       void    SetSize( size_t newSize );
       void    SetValues();
       void    GetArray();

       void    AddArray( const CArray &a );
       void    SubtractArray( const CArray &a );
       void    MultiplyArray( const CArray &a );

     private:
       std::vector<int> Val;
       int Size;
   };

   extern "C" 
   {
   void    Add( int*, int*, int*, int*);
   void    Subtract( int*, int*, int*, int*);
   void    Muliply( int*, int*, int *, int* );
   }
   ```

   With implementation like this:

   ```
   CArray::CArrary : Size(0)
   {}


   void CArray::SetSize( int newSize )
   {
     Val.resize(newSize);
     Size = newSize;
   }


   void CArray::SetValues()
   {
       for ( int i=0; i<Size; ++i )
       {
         cout << "Element " << i+1 << ": ";
         cin >> Val[i];
       }
   }


   void CArray::GetArray()
   {
       for ( int i=0; i<Size; ++)
       {
         cout << Val[i] << " ";
       }
   }


   void CArray::SubtractArray( const CArray &a )
   {

       Subtract( &Val[0], &a.Val[0], &Size, &a.Size);
       GetArray();
   }
   ```
3. `GetArray()` would be better renamed to `PrintArray()`, and ideally it should take a stream as parameter. `SetValues()` would be better named `ReadValuesFromInput()` or something similar.
4. You should take parameters of type `CArray` by const reference instead of by value. I already did this in the code above.
5. One function, one responsibility. `SubtractArray()` calling `GetArray()` is *wrong.*

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have taken a second look at your Fortran, I can tell your knowledge of the language is fairly limited.

1. `END` specifies the end of the program, not the end of the loop/if-statement/module (these are `ENDDO`/`END DO`, `ENDIF`/`END IF`, and `END MODULE` respectively)
2. `IMPLICIT NONE` means that all variables ***must*** be declared, and you never declared `i`
3. `RETURN` is not necessary, as the code will return once completed
4. While not necessary, you probably should declare `a` as `INTENT(INOUT)` and `b` as `INTENT(IN)` (though, admittedly, I am not sure if this screws up the C-Fortran interoperability).
5. You skipped an `END` (looks like for `IF`, given your indenting)

Your Fortran code should look more like

```
MODULE SubtractArrays
    USE ico_c_binding
    IMPLICIT NONE

  CONTAINS

    SUBROUTINE Subtract(a,b,s1,s2) bind(C,NAME='Subtract')
      INTEGER(INT_C), INTENT(IN) :: s1,s2
      INTEGER(INT_C), DIMENSION(s2), INTENT(IN) :: b
      INTEGER(INT_C), DIMENSION(s1), INTENT(INOUT) :: a
      INTEGER :: i

      IF(s1 == s2) THEN
         DO i=1,s1
            a(i) = a(i) - b(i)
         ENDDO
      ENDIF
    END SUBROUTINE
END MODULE
```

Comment: So if this is the correct code for fortran, does that mean that the way I wrote the "extern c" part in the C++ code is correct? I appreciate the help the Fortran, but I need to know how to code the C++ so that it correctly calls fortran. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help you on that part. My knowledge of C++ is limited to the fact that it exists.

Comment: I looked through your suggestions, and I noticed that you said I need to add INTEGER(INT_C). I have written mixed code before and have not had this problem. I am using the ifort compiler. I don't know it well enough to answer some of my questions and these things, but why would I need it now, when I did not need at the other times?

Comment: I would assume it is because you are using `int`, rather than `long int` or `long long int` in your C code (both `int` and `INTEGER` are 4-byte integer, whereas the other two are 8 bytes).

Comment: Why did you make everything capitalised? Do you actually prefer it that way?

Comment: @bdforbes: I capitalize keywords to distinguish them from variables. I do indeed prefer it that way.

Comment: Fair enough. My preference is syntax highlighting... with all caps it feels like the code is yelling at me...